# Unable to delete product in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, delete

I try to delete product but it returns exception can not delete product and sku 
my code is here

```
 $productcollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer','LG')->load();

        foreach ($productcollection as $product) {
            try {

                $this->productRepository->delete($product);
            } catch (StateException $e) {
            }
        }
```

how can I solve this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$productcollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer','LG')->load();
foreach ($productcollection as $product) {
    try {
        $productcollection->removeItemByKey($product->getId());
    } catch (StateException $e) {
    }
}
return $productcollection;
      }
```

Thankful of my friend Sandro who helped me with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to delete product from frontend then you need to assign area for that.

Add following code to your class.

```
public function __construct(
    ........
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    ......
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

Following code is for deleting product.

```
$this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
// using sku
$this->productRepository->deleteById('Z62676');

// using product id
$product = $this->productRepository->getById(1);
$this->productRepository->delete($product);
```

**Delete All Products Example using object manager :**

```
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('isSecureArea', true);
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
$app_state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$app_state->setAreaCode('frontend');

foreach ($collection as $product){
    try {
        echo 'Deleted '.$product->getName()."<br>";
        $product->delete();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Unable to delete product '.$product->getName()."<br>";
        echo $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Unable to apply data patch DevAll\ExtensionSettingConfig\Setup\Patch\Data\RemoveLGManufacturer for module DevAll_ExtensionSettingConfig. Original exception message: Registry key "isSecureArea" already exists.
I think using Registry is deprecated in Magento 2.3.3 .
Thanks for answer .

Comment: try without registry it may work.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Do some corrections in the code. Hopefully, it will work for you.

```
$productcollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer','LG')->load();
    foreach ($productcollection as $product) {
        try {
            $product->delete();
        } catch (StateException $e) {
        }
    }
```

This code will gives you result what you want.

Comment: you just changed ``` $this->productRepository->delete($product);``` by    $product->delete(); but it doesn't work=> Original exception message: Area code is not set

Comment: Where you are running this code? In the root PHP script? If yes, then you need to add frontend areacode above the code like this:
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

Comment: its datapatch  .

Comment: Yes i needed to add area code on frontend .