# Running data recurring

Tags: magento2, database, setup-upgrade

crated data patch but it stucks on setup:upgrade

```
Running data recurring...
```

my code is

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace DevAll\ExtensionSettingConfig\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepositoryIn;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
class RemoveLGManufacturer implements DataPatchInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    private $attributeRepository;

    private $_productRepositoryInterface;

    private $collectionFactory;

    private $state;

    private  $productCollectionFactory;

    private $productRepository;

    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    public function __construct(
        State $state,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepositoryInterface,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $state->setAreaCode('frontend') ;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->_productRepositoryInterface = $productRepositoryInterface;
        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
    public function apply()
    {
          //$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('manufacturer','LG')->create();





        $productcollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer','LG')->load();
        foreach ($productcollection as $product) {
            try {
                $this->_productRepositoryInterface->delete($product);
            } catch (StateException $e) {
            }
        }

    }

}
```

what can be the cause of problem ? how to fix it ?

Comment: I've noticed you are posting multiple variations of more or less the same question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307676/i-am-trying-to-create-datapatch-but-cant-delete-products https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307791/i-have-created-datapatch-to-delete-products-with-specific-value-on-attribute-man https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307859/unable-to-delete-product-in-magento2 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/308040/data-patch-changes-does-not-affect-database

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309173/i-created-data-patch-setupupgrade-never-finishes